# How to check if a user is logged in via Facebook in Firebase Auth

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to determine whether the current user is authenticated in the app via Facebook login or not. I want that because if a user is authenticated via facebook than the signOut() should process

```
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

but if it is authenticated via email than simple

```
auth.signOut();
```

my cuurent code is

```
//sign out method
public void signOut() {

    if(auth.getCurrentUser().getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        auth.signOut();
    }
    else {
        auth.signOut();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    for (UserInfo userInfo : firebaseUser.getProviderData()) {
        if (userInfo.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
            Log.d("TAG", "User is signed in with Facebook");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that if a user is logged in with email and the account is also linked to Facebook, this will return true but should return false. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: @Swapnil Why do you say it should return false? Please take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886378/checking-user-is-password-authenticated-or-with-some-provider).

Comment: You can't call userInfo.getProviderId() because it only returns "firebase" value.

Comment: @NaPro That's incorrect! FirebaseUser's [getProviderId()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getProviderId()) method, will always return a String which is the `PROVIDER_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you:

```
for (UserInfo user:FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
  if (user.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
    System.out.println("User is signed in with Facebook");
  } 
}
```