# Checking user is password authenticated or with some provider

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have simple user and password, Facebook and Google authentication in my application. And I want to do different actions on the password Authenticated user.

**Code**

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
            // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
            String providerId = profile.getProviderId();
            if(providerId.equals("facebook.com") | providerId.equals("google.com"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"fb or goole method is used",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Simmple method is used",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
```

**Problem:** Both if and else get executed in the loop. Any Solution?

Comment: So you basically say that once you are authenticated both Toast meassages appear?

Comment: Yes Exactly. Both Toast messages appear.

Comment: And you say that the user has a **single** account, let's say facebook and even with a single account both Toast meassages appear?

Comment: Yes. In case of google signin. which is single account. both messages get displayed. Facebook auth is not implemented properly yet.

Comment: There is no way to show both statements from a conditional statement unless there not multiple accounts. Can you show me the number of accounts from your Console?

Comment: I just have 2 accounts.

Comment: Both are different. One is google auth and one is simple password auth

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the following if statement:

```
if(providerId.equals("facebook.com") | providerId.equals("google.com")) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"fb or goole method is used",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Simmple method is used",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It means that if the `providerId` is **not** `facebook.com` or `google.com` it means that the user is authenticated with user and password but this statement is **inccorect**! In both cases, the user is authenticated with user and password. In case of `facebook.com` the user will be authenticated with the credentials that are coming from facebook and in case `google.com` the user will be authenticated with the credentials that are coming from `GoogleSignInAccount` object.

So what is happening if you are using that if statement, first it evaluates if the user is authenticated with user and password which obviously is since `user != null` and second will try to find the `providerId`, which can be `facebook.com` or `google.com`. That's why the order of displaying the Toast messages is `Simmple method is used` and second `fb or goole method is used`.

**Edit:** The simples way I can think of is to have three different authentication sections and to track which one was accessed by the user. If the user is pressing the google sign-in button then he is logged in with google and so on for the other types,

Comment: My Question is how can I distinguish between different types of auth?

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer this is how you can distinguish between different types of auth by getting the `providerId`. But user and password authentication is not different type of authentication in terms of `user.getProviderData()` because when authentication process is successful with google the user is already authenticated with user and password, that's why that message comes first. So if a user is authenticated with google or facebook it doesn't mean that he is **not** authenticated with user and passwod.

Comment: The simples way I can think of is to have three different authentication sections and to track which one was accessed by the user. If the user is pressing the google sign-in button then he is logged in with google and so on for the other types, right? That if statement will not help you achieve this.

Comment: right, Thanks for your Response. I got the solution. Let me put it as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was not specifying the Provider Id for the Password Authentication. I didn't even know the provider for password authentication. It is also not present in documentation. ( as far as I know )

So what i did is:

```
   String providerId = profile.getProviderId();
   Toast.makeText(this,providerId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Put these lines in loop to get provider id of password Authentication. which is `password` 
and filtered it using elseif.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
            // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
            String providerId = profile.getProviderId();
            Toast.makeText(this,providerId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(providerId.equals("facebook.com") | providerId.equals("google.com"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"fb or goole method is used",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(providerId.equals("password"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Simmple method is used",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
```